# How to extract specific pattern from a file in HP-UX

Tags: awk, sed, grep, perl, hp-ux

I would to like extract the pattern "/oracle" from a file.

I tried with "grep -w" command but it returned all the lines which have oracle word.

I need to extract only /oracle. Please tell me if any command grep,awk,sed gives my output

File Content:

```
   /oracle
   /oracle/client
   /oracle/T02
   /oracle/P02
   /oracle/R03
```

Comment: are there lines without `/oracle` in them? can there be more than one match in a line? what if you have matches like `/oracles`? if you have `-o` option, try `grep -o '/oracle'`... else try `sed -n 's#.*\(/oracle\).*#\1#p'`

Comment: Yes ther are lines without oracle as well. No One match in a line.

Comment: then you should change your sample data to include those other lines as well... and add complete expected output for clarity..

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -x` instead of `grep -w`:

```
$ grep -x "/oracle" test.txt
/oracle
```

Tested on Linux, but should apply to HP-UX, too. Else look at the manpage for "line-regexp" (instead of "word-regexp").

Answer (score -2):

I found a command in google and it worked perfectly.

```
awk "/^\/oracle$/" file_name
```